# Comparing ranking methods across multiple

Tags: correlation, multiple-comparisons, ranking, spearman-rho

I have a bunch of ranking algorithms that rank a collection of $k$ items. I have $n$ of these collections that I want to evaluate each algorithm on.
If I didn't have $n$ of these collections I would just use the Spearman rank to evaluate the correlation of each ranking algorithm to the true ranks, but how should I compare the algorithms when there are $n$ such collections I want to evaluate on?
I care about the ranks all equally, unlike in information retrieval where high ranked items are more important.

Comment: You mention the presence of true ranks, and so I presume that you are trying to compare each algorithm against the truth? Why can't you just calculate Spearman's rank separately for each algorithm-truth pair?

Comment: If I pool all $n$ collections of $k$ items it implies that I care about the relative ranks across collections, however, I don't. I only care that the approximate algorithms rank the $k$ items in the same order as the true ordering.